# Regex with javascript sorting

Tags: regex, sorting

Basically I have a function that is sorting product stock amounts.  But I can seem to get it to work correctly.

Here is the function:

```
function sortingData(a, b){
   a = ( a.match(/\d+/) || [] ).map(function (v) {return +v;});
   a = a[0];
   b = ( b.match(/\d+/) || [] ).map(function (v) {return +v;});
   b = b[0];
}
```

This is the array that's being returned:

```
0: " 1 In Stock _4567"
1: " 3 In Stock _4617"
2: " 3 In Stock _4613"
3: " 25 In Stock _4639"
4: " 25 In Stock _4637"
5: " 27 In Stock _4565"
6: " 28 In Stock _4633"
7: " 38 In Stock _4679"
8: " 451 In Stock _4521"
9: " 725 In Stock _4515"
10: " 846 In Stock _4499"
11: " 862 In Stock _4527"
12: " 1000 In Stock _4677"
13: " 1000 In Stock _4549"
14: " 2007 In Stock _4541"
15: " 2094 In Stock _4511"
16: " 2230 In Stock _4523"
17: " 2477 In Stock _4525"
18: " 2478 In Stock _4553"
19: " 2716 In Stock _4513"
20: " 3099 In Stock _4543"
21: " 3418 In Stock _4539"
22: " 4046 In Stock _4529"
23: " 4200 In Stock _4619"
24: " 4468 In Stock _4555"
25: " Out of Stock _4495"
26: " Out of Stock _4501"
27: " Out of Stock _4503"
28: " Out of Stock _4505"
29: " Out of Stock _4517"
30: " Out of Stock _4531"
31: " Out of Stock _4535"
32: " 4544 In Stock _4493"
33: " Out of Stock _4557"
34: " Out of Stock _4561"
```

The problem is: The 'Out of Stock' items are pulling the sku at the end as the regex.  I basically need a way to get these to show up at the end of the array, or just be excluded from the regex code.

I have tried `^(/d+)` as the regex, but that doesn't seem to work either.

Comment: Do you want to only match numbers at the start of the string? `/^\d+/`?